# Como añadir el control de SOUND en BigVideo.js

Tags: javascript, video

Estoy utilizando el plugin BIGVIDEO.JS:

http://johnpolacek.github.io/BigVideo.js/

Me han pedido añadir el control de sonido para poder mutearlo a conveniencia pero al poner los controles en TRUE solo me aparece el de PLAY.

Alguien sabe si este plug-in admite este tipo de control para el sonido? He buscado por internet y no consigo dar con ninguno que tenga instalado este control.

Estos son los parámetros que tengo disponibles.

```
var defaults = {
        // If you want to use a single mp4 source, set as true
        useFlashForFirefox:true,
        // If you are doing a playlist, the video won't play the first time
        // on a touchscreen unless the play event is attached to a user click
        forceAutoplay:true,
        controls:true,
        doLoop:true,
        container:$('body'),
        shrinkable:false
    };
```

Gracias :-)

Comment: Nunca he usado ninguno de los 2... pero revisando la documentación, se supone que puede obtener una instancia del player con la funcion `getPlayer()` y luego usando la function `volume(0)` para silenciar el volumen. O sea algo como: 
`BV.getPlayer().volume(0);`. Asi puede implementar su propio boton para poner / quitar el volumen

Comment: Desde 2015 se abandonó el proyecto, se ve difícil que puedas adaptarlo a las nuevas tecnologías. Lo bueno es que estaba basado en [video.js](https://videojs.com/), muy personalizable.